# nifi invokehttp post complex json

Tags: json, rest, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, apache-nifi

I trying to use InvokeHttpProcessor in Apache NiFi to perform POST request with complex JSON body.
Accordingly this tutorial: http://www.tomaszezula.com/2016/10/30/nifi-and-http-post-configuration

I know how to use **UpdateAttribute** processor to add name/value pairs and then apply an additional transformation via **AttributesToJSON**.

But how to deal with complex JSON?
For example I have to perform request to GoogleAnalytics reporting API, so I need to perform this request:

```
POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet

{
  "reportRequests":
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXX",
      "dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2014-11-01", "endDate": "2014-11-30"}],
      "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Try to use `ReplaceText` processor instead of creating attributes and then transforming them into JSON.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `GenerateFlowFile` and `ReplaceText` processors to provide a template as the flowfile content and then populate the actual values. Once that JSON object is formed as flowfile content, it should be easy to send it via `POST` using `InvokeHTTP`