# Apache Nifi invokehttp Post with complex json

Tags: apache-nifi

I have read the article [nifi invokehttp post complex json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003890/nifi-invokehttp-post-complex-json/) and i would like to ask an example with the following json, to completely understand the solution.
{ "dummy" : { "value" : "C", "type" : "Property" }, "loc" : { "type" : "property", "value" : { "coordinates" : [ 111.3, 222.1], "type" : "Point" } }, "te" : "oall", "@dummy" : [ "linkd" ], "id" : "idhere" }

Can you show me how to provide a template in replaceText?
I have also tried, with enaluateJsonPath and attributeToJson proccessors but invokehttp sents only one-line variables (te , id , @dummy).

I am using ApacheNifi 1.25.0 and i want to push some data with invokeHttp post.